# Multiple css classes in VeeValidate classNames

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vee-validate

Is it possible to set multiple classes in VeeValidate (option classNames)?

I am using VeeValidate for Vue.js for form validation. There are options:
'classes: true, classNames: valid and invalid css class.'

I would like to use bootstrap 'alert alert-warning'. However, when I add class names below, I get following error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'remove' on
>   'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('alert alert-warning') contains
>   HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.

Is there workaround for this scenario besides creating a new css class?

Code:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
classes: true,
classNames: {
    valid: '',
    invalid: 'alert alert-warning'
}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/2.1.5/src/utils/index.js#L320-L333) it's possible to pass array of classes.
Try this:

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  classes: true,
  classNames: {
    valid: '',
    invalid: ['alert', 'alert-warning']
  }
});
```

Comment: @czmafi00 You're welcome :) Don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: Sory, I have to have at least reputation 15 to accept an answer. I wont forget when I get the reputation. :)

Comment: @czmafi00 15+ rep is needed to upvote/downvote posts, for accepting an answer you need just 1 rep :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts